# Resharper refactoring to remove magic strings

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper

Is there such a thing?  Either as a part of the product or a plugin?  I can't see to find it.

I want to go from:

```
public DataTable Fetch() {
    return ExecuteDataTable(_ConnectionString, "pr_DetectAffectedOrderLines");
}
```

to:

```
private const string SP_DETECT_AFFECTED_ORDER_LINES="pr_DetectAffectedOrderLines";

public DataTable Fetch() {
    return ExecuteDataTable(_ConnectionString, SP_DETECT_AFFECTED_ORDER_LINES);
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

ReSharper | Refactor This (Ctrl-Shift-R) | Introduce field, then select to introduce constant.

Comment: does Resharper have a feature where I can define the rules for creating constants from magic strings (e.g. 1st letter of the Camel hump) and then have it create the constants with a single keystroke rather than having a dialog everytime?

Comment: +1 doh - used resharper for 2.5 years and hadn't ever used that combo (shameful icon)..

Comment: I wish that it would find all uses of a string or number in a solution (or subfolder) and replace them with the new field.

Comment: Not that you (at least I have to) mark the whole string before refactoring. Just having the caret inside the string 'MessageBox.Show(@"asdf")' will otherwise result in '_dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(@"asdf")'

Answer (score 3):

There is a direct shortcut to refactor: `Ctrl+R, Ctrl+F`.

There are 3 of them:

[image: menu screenshot]

Demo with the "Introduce Variable" as example:

[image: demon as gif]

Answer (score 2):

If you go the lightbulb menu you can turn it into a resource or into a verbatim string.

Comment: The lightbulb was not there.  Possibly, a setting that needs to be turned on.